# C++ Fraction class does not work on negatives

Tags: c++, class

I am trying to create a fraction class that can do operations on fractions just like the way we did it by hand in elementary school. It works fine with positive numbers but I have tried implementing it with negative numbers and I get breakpoint error. It would be great if someone can tell me what is wrong with it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class fraction
{
private:
    long int n;
    long int d;
    long int gcd();
public:
    fraction(long int, long int);
    long int num(); //returns num
    long int denom(); //returns denom
    void print(); //print fraction
    void reduce(); //reduce fraction to lowest terms
friend double convert(fraction); //convert function to double
friend fraction operator+ (fraction, fraction);//add two fractions, answer in reduced form
friend fraction operator- (fraction, fraction);//subtract two fractions, reduced
};

long int fraction::gcd()
{
    long int divisor = 0;
    for (long int i = 1; (i <= n && i <= d) ; i++)
    {
        if ((n % i == 0) && (d % i == 0))
        {
            divisor=i;
        }
    }
    return divisor;
}
fraction::fraction(long int x, long int y) //constructor
{
    n=x;
    d=y;
    if ((x <= 0) && (y <= 0))
    {
        n = -x;
        d = -y;
    }
}
void fraction::reduce() //change value of n and d
{
    long int num = n/gcd();
    long int denom = d/gcd();
    n = num;
    d = denom;
}
long int fraction::num()
{
    return n;
}
long int fraction::denom()
{
    return d;
}
void fraction::print() 
{
    cout << n << "/" << d;
}
fraction operator- (fraction x, fraction y) 
{
    x.reduce();
    y.reduce();
    fraction temp;
    temp.n = (x.n)*(y.d) - y.n*(x.d);
    temp.d = (x.d)*(y.d); 
    temp.reduce();
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    fraction f(-5,100), g(-1,-2);
    (f-g).print; //returns error!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: Also, posting the error message would be helpful.

Comment: Where are your parentheses when calling `print()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that `print()` is a non-`const` member function.

When you use:

```
(f-g).print();
```

The function is called an a temporary object, which is good for calling `const` member functions, not non-`const` member functions.

You can resolve this problem by:

1. Changing `print()` to a `const` member function.
2. By assigning `f-g` to an object and calling `print` on that object.

   ```
    fraction res = f-g;
    res.print();
   ```

I would recommend using the first method.

**Update**

You have a problem in `gcd` when either `n` or `d` is negative. Change it to:

```
long int fraction::gcd()
{
   long int divisor = 1;

   // Deal with only positive numbers when computing the gcd.
   long int tempN = n < 0 ? -n : n;
   long int tempD = d < 0 ? -d : d;

   for (long int i = 1; (i <= tempN && i <= tempD) ; i++)
   {
      if ((tempN % i == 0) && (tempD % i == 0))
      {
         divisor=i;
      }
   }
   return divisor;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is an issue either. Even when I eliminated the print function and just called the expression `f-g;` the code still doesn't work.

Comment: @shoestringfries, that is one problem. The second problem is in `gcd`. See the updated answer.

Comment: I think that was the problem. Thank you :D